Limit of $4^n\cdot (x_n-2)$, where $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_n+2}$
Let’s define a sequence $x_1=4$ and $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_n+2}$ for $n\geq 2$. We know that this series converges to 2. But what is the limit of $4^n\cdot (x_n-2)$?
I know that $4^n\cdot (x_n-2)$ is a positive, decreasing sequence hence it converges, I just don’t know how to get the limit.

Let $x_1 = e^{a}+e^{-a}$ where $a$ is such that $e^a+e^{-a}=4$. Then the limit is $a^2$

@HariShankar, I see why that substitution is useful, but I don’t understand how you had the conclusion that the limit is $a^2$.

@PeterSimon Based on Hari Shankar's comment/hint, if you recursively try and find $x_n$ in terms of $a$, then you'll find that $x_n=e^{a/2^{n-1}}+e^{-a/2^{n-1}}$. If this is the form for $x_n$, then what does $\lim_{n \to \infty} 4^n(x_n-2)$ end up being?

Let $y_n=4^n(x_n-2)>0$,
$$
y_{n+1}=4^{n+1}(x_{n+1}-2)=4^{n+1}(\sqrt{x_n+2}-2)=4^{n+1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{y_n}{4^n}+4}-2\right)\\
y_{n+1}-y_n=8\cdot4^n\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{y_n}{4\cdot4^n}}-1-\frac{y_n}{8\cdot4^n}\right)
$$
We have $\sqrt{1+x}<1+\frac{x}{2}$ for $x>0$, so $y_{n+1}-y_n<0$, $\{y_n\}$ is a positive, decreasing sequence and thus converges.

Let ${\rm e}^a+{\rm e}^{-a}=4$, $x_n={\rm e}^{\frac{a}{2^{n-1}}}+{\rm e}^{-\frac{a}{2^{n-1}}}$, so
$$
y_n=4^n\left({\rm e}^{\frac{a}{2^n}}-{\rm e}^{-\frac{a}{2^n}}\right)^2=4^n\left(2\frac{a}{2^n}+o\left(a\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)\right)^2\to4a^2.
$$

We can work out that the value of that limit $4a^2$ is $4 \log(2+\sqrt{3))^2 \approx 6.9375$, which agrees with numerical analysis.
